# long lines in git or svn

Tags: git, svn, json

I am coding a program which has persistent data (the [MELT monitor](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/jit/2013-q4/msg00025.html), related to [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)). The data is persistent because it is expected to be read and overwritten by most executions. (That data is in particular made of abstract syntax trees)

Currently, this persistent data is an [Sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) database. Of course, I am backing up it in textual format, obtained by [sqlite dump](https://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html), and I want to manage this textual dump with a version control system (probably [git](http://git-scm.com/documentation), but perhaps also [subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) ....).

Unless I take special precautions, these SQL dumps will probably have quite long lines (e.g. several dozens of kilobytes). Wide SQL columns would probably contain JSON text of many kilobytes.

Would `git` (and `svn`) be more happy with shorter lines (in particular would they perform slower with long lines, or have repositories using much more disk space)?

I'm probably not mostly interested in the `diff` commands (e.g. `git diff` or `svn diff`), because I expect that using them for such textual dump is not very interesting for the human developers.

I am coding the persistency routines, so I am able to change slightly the format (e.g. to add newlines in some JSON text, which `sqlite3 dump` is dumping verbatim).

If you are curious, my current code snapshot is on http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/monimelt-bgc-21apr2014.tar.bz2 and contains a `state-monimelt.sql` dump file (which will of course become much larger, perhaps near or above a megabyte)

Comment: If you do not care about the human-readability or performing meaningful diffs, you can compress the text. It will it take less space and does not require newline substitutions across platforms, so it should perform better.

Comment: I sometimes care about the human readability. The persistent data is somehow abstract syntax tree in a domain specific language....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Svn basically stores the diffs between subsequent versions, so breaking the lines as to minimize the size of the diff should minimize the amount of storage you use.  Git compresses its revisions somewhat differently, so breaking the lines may not matter as much.  Whether it's significant in practice you can only tell by measuring.  My recommendation is to try it manually both ways and see if it makes enough difference to bother automating.  Just make sure to run a `git gc` to get the full effect of git's compression.

Comment: Subversion does not use a line-based diff in its storage, it uses xdelta (a binary diff algorithm). It is not necessarily true that longer lines will result in larger xdeltas.

Comment: I did not know that, thank you.  Still, that validates my admonition to test it first.